# How to connect two apps in docker-compose that are connected to two seprate networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which has two services: mysql database and api. Currently they're running on the same network which is fine but what I WANT IS TO CREATE TWO SEPRATE NETWORKS AND COMMUNICATE THEM IN SOME WAY. How should I approach this kind of problem?

```
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: mysqld
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shopping_list

    networks:
      - my-network
  
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: simple-python-server
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --reload
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DB: shopping_list
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:

volumes:
  todo-mysql-data:
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to have them on separate networks?

Comment: (For most cases I'd use the single `default` network that Compose provides automatically, and have no `networks:` blocks at all anywhere in the file.)

Comment: @SobhanRM This is for the educational purposes only. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second network to each of the containers that has the same name. They should then be able to reach each other.